# USB headset volume low on some ports

Tags: windows, usb, audio, drivers, headset

I have a Plantronics USB headset that I have been using on a number of computers for several years with no problems. I have had a new laptop (Dell Latitude 5520 running Windows 10 Enterprise Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1415)) for about three months and have been using the headset on the same USB-A port without problems until two or three weeks ago when the volume became low. Even with all controls at 100% the volume was lower than I prefer, making online meetings difficult.

Two weeks ago I tried plugging the headset into the other USB-A port and it worked normally again; until this morning when the volume was again low. I tried switching between the two USB-A ports but volume now remains low on both of them. I also have one free USB-C port and as I have a USB-C to USB-A adapter I plugged into that and the volume is again normal.

My concern is that this may not last and if this port also becomes affected by the same problem, I will have no more ports to use and will then be stuck with lowered volume.

As the headset works normally on different ports (and computers) the problem would appear to lie with software or drivers. I have tried uninstalling drivers for the Plantronics Audio 628 USB controller, disconnecting the headset and reconnecting it so the driver will reinstall but this has had no effect. Can anyone suggest other possible solutions?

Comment: Have you asked Plantronics?   That would be the first thing that I myself would do in this case.  If this is a known issue, their support department is bound to know about it.

Comment: I haven't. They don't exist anymore having been rolled up with Polycom into a new entity, Poly. I looked at their headset support page but they don't make it easy, you must drill down into their existing products. Didn't see any sign of asking for assistance on old products, but will have another look. Though I suspect that this is somehow a USB subsystem issue rather than with the headset or its drivers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantronics - this suggests they acquired Polycom and renamed parent company Plantronics to "Poly". I doubt this absolves them from warranty claims of Plantronics products. You should definitely just ask them!

Comment: I've used their Email Support feature to contact them and ask if they have any troubleshooting advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received feedback from Poly that has solved the problem. They said

> We can see that you are using 11th Gen intel PC which is running Intel
> SST driver which has known bug with USB audio devices. Please disable
> it and then restart PC, then update realtek driver manually from PC
> manufacturer's website and then test performance.

and simply disabling the SST driver and restarting has my audio levels back to normal on one of the ports that were originally affected. I did not need to update the Realtek driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced that issue while ago. I found a solution. This is the one that worked for me. I'm using windows 11 operating system and the laptop is Asus TUF fx507. The solution that worked for me was going to settings->system->sound->more sound settings
In that menu select the device and open the properties for it. Under general click properties, click the button that says change settings, then select Driver-> Uninstall device, and be sure to check the box that says attempt to uninstall device drivers. Once it was uninstalled I removed the USB and then restarted my PC, then when I plugged my headset back in the sound was back to normal and much louder.